# Fill in data if the the column are empty

Tags: c#

**Using**

1. Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18
2. Microsoft Visual Basic

**Case :**
I have identify and display the data from SQL. But I want to convert them into one column.

My Table : This is a payment data, CardType-'E' does not have data in 'Manufacturer', 'CardNo' will fill in the the empty slot if CardType = 'E'.

**Example goal**
Before :

```
Column A    Column B   Column C
 Data 1      Data 2      Y
             Data 3      N
 Data 4                  Y
```

After :

```
Column A  Column C
Data 1     Y
Data 3     N
Data 4     Y
```

My table : [image: This is a payment data, CardType-'E' does not have data in 'Manufacturer', 'CardNo' will fill in the the empty slot if 'E'.]

Sample output : [image: Sample output]

What have I got? ( A IF statement which output the data)

```
if (transactions.Count != 0)
                {
                    Dictionary<string,string> EncodedLaneCode = new Dictionary<string,string>();
                    foreach(var x in LaneCodeList)
                    {
                        EncodedLaneCode.Add(x,Utils.GetEncoded(x.ToString()).ToString());
                    } 

                    foreach (var t in transactions)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = TDataTable.NewRow();
                        dr["ManufacturerNo"] = t.ManufacturerNo;
                        dr["CardNo"] = t.CardNo;
                       
                        // T/E
                        dr["CardTypeTag"] = t.CardTypeTag;
                        

                        dr["TransactionTime"] = t.TransactionTime;
                        //EntryLocation
                        string locationName = cpms.ParkingLevels.Where(c => c.ZoneCode == t.SPID && c.LevelCode == t.EntryLocation || c.LocationID == t.EntryLocation).Select(c=>c.LevelName).FirstOrDefault();
                        dr["EntryLocation"] = locationName;
                        dr["EntryReaderId"] = t.EntryReaderId;
                        dr["EntryTime"] = t.EntryTime?.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt");

                        //EntryLane


                        //var LanecodeKey = EncodedLaneCode.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == t.EntryLane).Key;
                       //string entrylaneName/ = cpms.Lanes.Where(c => c.LaneCode == LanecodeKey).Select(c => c.LaneName).FirstOrDefault();
                        //dr["EntryLane"] = entrylaneName1;

                        string entrylaneName = cpms.Lanes.Where(c => c.LaneCode == "P" + t.EntryLane).Select(c => c.LaneName).FirstOrDefault();
                        dr["EntryLane"] = entrylaneName;

                        dr["ExitLocation"] = locationName;
                        dr["ExitReaderId"] = t.ExitReaderId;
                        dr["ExitTime"] = t.ExitTime?.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt");

                        string exitlaneName = cpms.Lanes.Where(c => c.LaneCode == t.ExitLane).Select(c => c.LaneName).FirstOrDefault();
                        dr["ExitLane"] = exitlaneName;

                        dr["TransactionAmount"] = (Convert.ToDouble(t.TransactionAmount)/100).ToString("0.00");
                        dr["Surcharge"] = (Convert.ToDouble(t.Surcharge)/100).ToString("0.00");
                        dr["Fare"] = (Convert.ToDouble(t.Fare)/100).ToString("0.00");
                        dr["BatchNo"] = t.BatchNo;

                        TDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < TDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                        olvSearch.AddObject(TDataTable.Rows[i]);
                }
```

Comment: Do you want to fill the missing column already when inserting or when retrieving the data?

Comment: when retrieving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the value of `ManufacturerNo` is null or empty and simply use `CardNo` instead.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.ManufacturerNo))
{
    dr["ManufacturerNo"] = t.CardNo;
}
else
{
    dr["ManufacturerNo"] = t.ManufacturerNo;
}
```

or in short

```
dr["ManufacturerNo"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.ManufacturerNo) ? t.CardNo : t.ManufacturerNo;
```

Comment: Would you mind to accept the answer since it helped with your problem, please.